# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project nextrtc-signaling-serverrror

Tags: java, spring, maven, eclipse-rcp

I tested nextrtc-signaling-server which is opensource for Java.
But I encountered building Maven problem. I hope that this is solved.

**My console log.**

```
 [INFO] Building jar: D:\signallinServer\nextrtc-signaling-server\target\nextrtc-signaling-server-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) @ nextrtc-signaling-server ---
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 12.430 s
 [INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-29T11:12:34+09:00
 [INFO] Final Memory: 26M/223M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project nextrtc-signaling-server: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1]  http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

**POM.xml**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.nextrtc.signalingserver</groupId>
<artifactId>nextrtc-signaling-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>nextrtc-signaling-server</name>
<url>http://nextrtc.org</url>
<description>Library providing signaling protocol for WebRTC</description>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>MIT License</name>
        <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Marcin Ślósarz</name>
        <email>m.slosarz@ahej.pl</email>
        <organization>NextRTC</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://nextrtc.org</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
</developers>

<issueManagement>
    <url>https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-signaling-server/issues</url>
    <system>GitHub Issues</system>
</issueManagement>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-signaling-server.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:mslosarz/nextrtc-signaling-server.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-signaling-server</url>
</scm>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring-version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.zohhak</groupId>
        <artifactId>zohhak</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've built this source at "clean package exec: Java" (Maven Goals)

What do I have to do?
I really want to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build nextrtc-signaling-server project (https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-signaling-server) using below command.

```
mvn clean package
```

If there is a main class (for example MySampleApplication.java) in a project with package (for example com.sample.my) then you can run that using below command.

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.sample.my.MySampleApplication"
```

If you want to develop new application using "nextrtc-signaling-server" then add below maven dependency in your maven project. Please refer https://nextrtc.org/archives/85

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.nextrtc.signalingserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>nextrtc-signaling-server</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. but I got another error. I found it. but that was not my solution.
Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn".

Comment: Are you running this in eclipse? If yes then use above commands without mvn in Goals.

Comment: Have you ever experienced project using nextRTC?
If you have, There is something I need to impement in the code. but there is no description about how to make it and what it is.

If I sovle that error, I will get code error.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do much work for fix this problem. Simply go to your maven repository which is located under services and then right click and select add repository then add the repository name.In this case it should be org.codehaus...
See it works